# PHP Read a ftp file line by line from localhost

Tags: php, fopen, fread

I have a text file stored on a ftp account. I have the hostname, username and the password.  I dont know what is the name of the file, but i know that on root there is only 1 file. I have to read that file line by line and store that content into a php variable.

This is what i have tryed:

```
$ftp_server = "myhostname";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user_name = "myusename";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypassword";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { } 
else {  
ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true ); 

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");   

    $filename = $contents[0]; //name of the file

    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $file_content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));        
    print_r($file_content);         

}
```

I run this script from my localhost, but it seems it trys to read a file stored in the same folder where is this php file insted of reading from the ftp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download a file from FTP with `ftp_get` first and then `fopen` and `fread` on local machine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: I managed to read it on my localhost and it works, but i hoped i could read it there without downloading it. Are you sure that this is the only way possible?

Comment: Yes, I guess. At least FTP tools I know downloads files to some temp folder and then process them locally.

Comment: OK. Btw, do you have any issue with storing file locally? For example, do you need only partial download, or have no permission to write to local filesystem, etc? Because that can be colved, if necessary.

Comment: It's ok, i solved the problem after all downloading the file localy. Thx